# Firefox multiple iframes

Tags: wordpress, firefox, iframe, twitter, facebook-like

I have a problem with multiple iframe in firefox on my wordpress site.
I have a twitter "tweet" button and a facebook "like" button. Both of them are iframes that I embed on my site. So far no problem. BUT when I make a post which has got an iframe embedded Vimeo clip in it, the Vimeo clip gets replaced by the "like" button, and the "tweet" button has taken the "like" buttons original position.

I have tested this in Firefox and Chrome. In Chrome it all looks good, but not in FF.

The facebook embed code:

```
<iframe id="facebook" name="facebook" src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=<?php echo($url); ?>&amp;layout=button_count&amp;show_faces=false&amp;width=90&amp;action=like&amp;font&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=21" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:90px; height:21px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

The Twitter embed code:

```
<script src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<a href="http://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button">Tweet</a>
```

The embedded Vimeo code in the post:

```
<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/22382565?color=17bcda" width="400" height="225" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

If you look at the top post there should be a Vimeo clip just below "testing testing testing...". And on the left sidebar you can see the two tweet buttons, which should be one tweet and one like. I want to point out though that all of this is working fine at my localhost. http://www.bentrovato.se/index_wp.php/

Any idea what the problem could be?

Comment: There isn't any difference between Firefox 3.5 and the latest Chrome when I check it.

Comment: Ok. Hmmm. I have FF 3.6 and Mac OSX 10.6

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and fixed it by clearing cache

Click the `Firefox` button > `Options` > `Options` > `Advanced`.
In the `Cached Web Content` section click on `Clear Now`.